# Retrieve state of HubConnection

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, signalr

There used to be a `State` property on SignalR's `HubConnection` that exposed a `ConnectionState` enum:

- Connecting
- Connected
- Reconnecting
- Disconnected

How do I find the connection state in SignalR Core?

```
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://foo.com")
                .Build();

Console.Write(_connection.State); //Won't compile, no State property.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public equivalent to connection state for ASP.NET Core SignalR (at the moment). You have to rely on awaiting the StartAsync method task to know that you're in the connected state and the Closed event from the HubConnection to know that you're disconnected.